# Iterating through subqueries in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have made a system to implement custom views for different clients with `SQLAlchemy`  like this:

file with standard views:

```
def get_standard_views():
    standard_views_list = []
    for standard_view in [obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__])
                          if inspect.isclass(obj) and obj.__module__ == __name__]:
        standard_views_list.append(standard_view())
    return standard_views_list

class InvoiceFactView:

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = "view_invoice_fact"

        current_task_per_process_view = sa.select( 
            pd.id_process_v360,
            tag_d.name.label("tag_name"),
            task_def.task_name.label("task_name"),
            sa.sql.func.greatest(
                pd.process_updated_at,
                tag_d.updated_at_tag,
                task_def.updated_at_task_definition
            ).label('last_refresh_at')
        ).select_from(
            join(inv_fact, pd, pd.process_key == inv_fact.process_key_process_dim) 
            .join(td, td.id_task_v360 == pd.recent_task_id)
            .join(task_def, task_def.task_definition_key == td.task_definition_key_task_definition_dim)
            .outerjoin(tta, tta.task_definition_key_task_definition_dim == task_def.task_definition_key)
            .outerjoin(tag_d, tag_d.tag_key == tta.tag_key_tag_dim)
        ).where(
            pd.completion_type == None
        ).group_by( 
            pd.id_process_v360,
            tag_d.name,
            task_def.task_name,
            pd.process_updated_at,
            tag_d.updated_at_tag,
            task_def.updated_at_task_definition
        )

        self.query = sa.select(
            tdd.id_tax_document_v360.label("ID V360"),
            inv_fact.total_value,
            pd.id_process_v360,
            pd.workflow_name,
            pd.completion_type,
            tdd.issue_date,
            pd.process_created_at.label("process_created_at"),
            pd.process_completed_at.label("process_completed_at"),
            tdd.business_unit.label("business_unit"),
            sd.supplier_name.label("supplier_name"),
            sd.supplier_cnpj.label("supplier_cnpj"),
            cd.customer_name,
            city.name.label('invoice_city_name'),
            func.substring(doct.document_type,'^\w+::(\w+)').label("document_type"),
            current_task_per_process_view.c.tag_name,
            current_task_per_process_view.c.task_name,
            sa.sql.func.greatest(
                pd.process_updated_at,
                tdd.tax_updated_at,
                current_task_per_process_view.c.last_refresh_at
            ).label('last_refresh_at')
        ).select_from( 
            join(inv_fact, tdd, tdd.tax_document_key == inv_fact.tax_document_key_tax_document_dim) 
            .join(pd, pd.process_key == inv_fact.process_key_process_dim) 
            .join(doct, doct.document_type_key == inv_fact.document_type_key_document_type_dim)
            .outerjoin(city, city.id_city_v360 == tdd.invoice_issue_city)
            .outerjoin(sd, sd.supplier_key == inv_fact.supplier_key_supplier_dim)
            .outerjoin(cd, cd.customer_key == inv_fact.customer_key_customer_dim)
            .outerjoin(current_task_per_process_view, current_task_per_process_view.c.id_process_v360 == pd.id_process_v360)
        )
```

file that catches the standard views and allows me to manipulate them according to each client's needs:

```
from DWViewsStandard import *

class DWViewsBancoBV:

    excluded_views = []
    custom_views = []
    client_name = "bancobv"

    def __init__(self):
        standard_views = get_standard_views()
        for view in standard_views:
            if view.name == 'view_invoice_fact':
                view.query = sa.select(
                        view.query.c
                    ).add_columns(
                        case((srd.systur_supplier_identification_number != None, True), else_=False).label('flag_supplier_receptivo')
                    ).select_from(
                        outerjoin(view.query, srd, view.query.c.supplier_cnpj == srd.systur_supplier_identification_number)
                    )
                
            if view.name not in self.excluded_views:
                self.custom_views.append(view)

    def get_custom_views(self):
        return self.custom_views
```

file that implements the view in the database:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDLElement
from sqlalchemy.sql import table
from DWViewsCustomer import *
import inspect, sys, urllib.parse, os

class CreateView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name, selectable):
        self.name = name
        self.selectable = selectable

@compiler.compiles(CreateView)
def _create_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS %s; CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW %s AS %s" % (
        element.name,
        element.name,
        compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.selectable, literal_binds=True),
    )

def view(name, metadata, selectable):
    t = table(name)

    t._columns._populate_separate_keys(
        col._make_proxy(t) for col in selectable.selected_columns
    )

    sa.event.listen(
        metadata,
        "after_create",
        CreateView(name, selectable)
    )
    return t

pwd = urllib.parse.quote_plus(os.getenv('PWD_INTERNAL'))
engine = sa.create_engine(f"postgresql://"+os.getenv('USER_INTERNAL')+":"+pwd+"@"+os.getenv('HOST_INTERNAL')+"/dw_general_info", echo=False)
query = sa.select(sa.column('v360_customer_name'), sa.column(
    'active_views'), sa.column('dw_name')).select_from(sa.table('dw_etl_info'))
with engine.begin() as conn:
    client_option = conn.execute(query)
    print('Metadata table fetched')

for row in client_option:
    v360_customer_name = row.v360_customer_name
    active_views = row.active_views
    dw_name = row.dw_name

    if active_views:
        for class_ in [obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['DWViewsCustomer']) if inspect.isclass(obj) and obj.__module__ == 'DWViewsCustomer']:
            if class_.client_name == v360_customer_name:
                engine = sa.create_engine(
                    "postgresql://"+os.getenv('USER_INTERNAL')+":"+pwd+"@"+os.getenv('HOST_INTERNAL')+"/{}".format(dw_name), echo=True)
                metadata = sa.MetaData()
                custom_views = class_().get_custom_views()
                print(f"Running for {dw_name}")
                for view_query in custom_views:
                    print(f"Creating {view_query.name}")
                    view(view_query.name, metadata, view_query.query)
                    print(f"{view_query.name} successfully created")
                with engine.begin() as conn:
                    metadata.create_all(conn)
```

I can add custom columns for each client as I am doing here. But how can I drop a subquery that I don't want to use? Like, in this case, what if I don't want to use any info related to the current_task_per_processes_view? How can I ignore it in the custom views file?

I have tried a lot of solutions but I don't have any ideas.